# Use Azure Stream Analytics for a simple Data pass-through

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I want to build an IoT-Architecture with Azure Services. The Data comes from different IoT-Devices and gets received by an Event-Hub. The Event-Hub passes the Data to a Stream Analytics Service and to a Worker Role. The Worker Role should calculate parameters and pass them to a Service-Bus-Queue. The Stream Analytics Service should simply act as a "Storage Writer" and pass the Data through into a Blob-Storage, for the case that we need more explicit Data later.

Is Stream Analytics the right Service for this purpose or is it kind of oversized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using Azure Stream Analytics to perform low latency writes to blob storage without any data transformation (as a passthrough) is a supported scenario.  You would implement this with a SELECT * FROM [input] query.